# Iterate dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

(first time I post here!! Been through the whole forum tho, but couldn't find any solutions)

I'm trying to iterate through a dataframe (matrix [846:19]) and identify objects who lies 3 stDev from the mean.

I've identified the values:

```
r <- (mapply(v, FUN = sd)*3 + mapply(v, FUN = mean))
```

However, when I try to loop through the df (named 'v')

```
    for (i in c(1:19)){
      for (j in c(1:19)){
        out[i] <- which(v[[j]]> r[j])
        }
       }
```

I get the error

```
Error in out[i] <- which(v[[j]] > r[j]) : replacement has length zero
```

side note: when I do it manually (i.e.)

```
which(v$Rad.Ra>r[5])
```

it works! :o

any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: which can return 0, 1 or many results, can't fit those in 1 element of array.

Comment: In the inner loop `out[i]` does not depend on `j` so it's rewritten 19 times and only the last value is kept. Apart from the error, your code's logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `for` loops to do what you describe in the question.
I will use `colMeans` to get the column means and `apply` to get the standard errors. Most of the code that follows is vectorized, the R way of solving problems.

First a dataset example, since you have posted none.

```
set.seed(3623)
v <- matrix(rnorm(846*19), ncol = 19)
```

Now the problem.

```
r <- colMeans(v) + apply(v, 2, sd)*3
w <- which(t(apply(v, 1, `>`, r)), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

If you want a matrix with the rows and columns where the values greater than 3 standard errors are, the matrix `w` holds those values.

```
head(w)
#     row col
#[1,] 647   1
#[2,] 124   4
#[3,] 523   4
#[4,] 631   4
#[5,] 775   5
#[6,] 607   6
```

If you want a list with just the row numbers, `split` the above matrix by column.

```
split(w[, 1], w[, 2])
```